# How to put at end of line?

Tags: normal-mode

How to put at end of line with vim?

I would like to use `p` to put some text at the end of the current line without moving the cursor.

Edit:

For example I would like to copy a word to the end of the line so I use `yw` to copy the word and then how can I put it to the end of the current line?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: If you want a mapping you could try this: ```nnoremap ,p m'yiw$p`` ```. Hit `,p` and the word under the cursor should be pasted at the end of the line. You don't need the space at the end, it's here because I don't know how to format code containing a double backtick without it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want your cursor back to its previous position after putting the text at the end of the line you could use marks:

```
ma$p`a
```

- `ma` sets the mark `a` to the current position
- `$p` As explained is the other answers put the text at the end of the line
- `(backtick)a` go back to the position marked by `ma`

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly, you want to **put** a word at the end of the line.

You can do that with:

```
$p
```

`$` move the cursor to the end of the line, `p` put.

The `print` command on the other hand, is used to display lines of your file, e.g.

```
:1,2p "print the first and second line.
```

Ref:

- `:h p`  (put)
- `:h :p` (print)

Answer (score 3):

You want to "put", not "print".

1. Move the cursor to the end of the line with `$`.
2. Press `p` to "put" the content of the unnamed register (what you yanked with `yw`) after the cursor.

See `:help p`, `:help registers`, `:help :print`.

Comment: yes, put sorry! However I would like to print to the end of line without moving the cursors. Is this possible?

Comment: No. You need to move the cursor to where you want to put.